# How to see if the background process is complete in SQLDEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, csv, background, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a csv unload process i am running in sqldeveloper, a process window popped up showing the progress of the export and it had an option to run the process in background, I picked the option but now how do I know if the process is complete?

Answer (score 179):

You will see a running task in the Task Progress View by clicking on View -> Task Progress.

From menu of Oracle Sql Developer

1. Choose `View`.
2. Then choose `Task Progress`.
3. The view will appear in tab located in lower right corner.

**`View -> Task Progress`**

[image: View Task Progress Menue]
[image: Task Progress View Tab]

Comment: @shareef Be careful with your edits, you radically changed the answer here, and introduced multiple grammatical errors.

Comment: thanks i shall be more carefull but i think its improved now @Simon LG

Comment: Na versão em pt_BR as opções são Exibir -> Andamento da Tarefa.

Comment: En français: "Progression de tâche"

Comment: En español: "Ver - Progreso de Tarea"